# Angular 2: @angular/common/index has no exported mng 'NgSwitchWhen'

Tags: angular

this seems to be a breaking change, but I cannot find any documentation on this.

What is the preferred alternative to NgSwitchWhen?

PS: It did work under angular2 rc.1

Comment: Can you please try `NgSwitchCase` instead?

Comment: Why do you need to import it anyway?

Comment: I dont.. just realized that :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to import ngSwitch angular 2 do it by default

```
    <span [ngSwitch]="Foo">
       <template *ngSwitchCase="1"> Yes</template>
       <template *ngSwitchCase="0">No</template>
     </span>
```

For more [see doc for *ngSwitchCase](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html)

even if you want to import

```
  import {NgSwitch, NgSwitchCase, NgSwitchDefault} from '@angular/common';
```

directives

```
  directives: [NgSwitch, NgSwitchCase, NgSwitchDefault]
```